# Is there a better way to query multiple sites without using a loop for this API

Tags: r

need to access data from the data.gov.uk using API's but cannot find any info regarding how to construct a query that includes a list within the API query rather than using a loop.

the code below is the only way I can extract my data so far - using R

```
> 
> siteList<-list("TH-PTTR0016","TH-PMLE0063","TH-PTNE0072","TH-PBVR0006","TH-PTTB0002","TH-PMLR0035", "TH-PTTB0012", "TH-PTSE0072",
+  "TH-PTNE0008", "TH-PTTB0007")
> 
> Resultall<-data.frame()
> for(i in siteList)
+ {tmp<-read.csv(paste0("http://environment.data.gov.uk/water-quality/id/sampling-point/",i,"/measurements.csv?&_limit=99999"))
+ Resultall<-rbind(Resultall,tmp)}
```

This method is extremely slow and would greatly appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We could use asynchronous requests with the crul package. Reference: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/crul/vignettes/async.html

```
library(crul)
library(glue)

cc <- Async$new(
  urls = glue(
    "http://environment.data.gov.uk/",
    "water-quality/id/sampling-point/{ siteList }/measurements.csv",
    "?&_limit=99999"
  )
)

res <- cc$get()

Resultall <- 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(z) {
    read.csv(text = z$parse("UTF-8"))
  }))
```

`system.time()` for this method gives 5.6 seconds vs. 13.7 for OP.

Faster yet is to use data.table's fread for parsing:

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(lapply(res, function(z) {
  fread(text = z$parse("UTF-8"))
}))
```

Comment: Thank you, both methods look really good and will try both within my shiny app